# Automatically adding width and height attributes to <img> tags with a PHP function

Tags: php, html, html-sanitizing, getimagesize

What I want is a function I can run on user input that will intelligently find and add the `width` and `height` attributes to any `<img>` tag in a blob of HTML so as to avoid page-reflowing issues while images load.

I am writing the posting script for a PHP forum, where a user's input is sanitised and generally made nicer before writing it to the database for later display. As an example of what I do to make things nicer, I have a script that inserts `alt` attributes into images like so:

`Here are two images: <img src="http://example.com/image.png"> <img src="http://example.com/image2.png">`

which, upon sanitising by the posting script, becomes

`Here are two images: <img src="http://example.com/image.png" alt="Posted image"> <img src="http://example.com/image2.png" alt="Posted image">`

(This makes it validate under HTML 4 strict, but maybe isn't in the spirit of the alt attribute—alas!)

So, for my function, I have a vague idea that the server will need to run `getimagesize()` on each external image it finds in the block of HTML, then apply the attributes that function generates to each and every `<img>` tag it runs into. I assume that this function has been written before, but I have had no luck on Google or php.net docs. Do I have to start from scratch, or is somebody aware of a (relatively) robust function that I can use or adapt to do this job?

Comment: I believe you will need to fetch and write the image to a file, then run getimagesize() on that to get its width and height. Once you are done with it you can unlink($pathToFile) to delete it

Comment: Something more efficient to do would be having a layout that doesn't break/reflow with images loading; or perhaps use client-sided scripting to manipulate width and height attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right about `getimagesize()`. You can simply do something like this:

```
$img = 'image2.png';
$info = getimagesize($img);
printf('<img src="%s" %s>', $img, $info[3]);
```

If the image is hosted at a remote location, you'll have to download all the images though (the function takes care of it), so you might want to cache the result to speed things up on subsequent requests.

**Edit:** Just saw that you have a string containing various `<img>` elements. This should do the trick:

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOF
something <img src="https://www.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo_lg.gif"> hello <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/5/logo1.png">
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img->getAttribute('src'));
    $img->setAttribute('width', $width);
    $img->setAttribute('height', $height);
}

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$newDom = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/p')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    $newDom->appendChild($newDom->importNode($node, true));
}

$newHtml = $newDom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: actually, caching the results is a good idea regardless of the where the images are stored.

Comment: I'm very grateful for you walking through the DOM process, as it was what scared me. I will try using this code now.

Comment: I'm slowly implementing this, and am currently puzzling through an if() check that ensures that I don't end up with `width="" height=""` if PHP fails to retrieve the image.

I've also noticed that if my HTML string is simply `<img ...> <img ...> <img ...> ` nothing is returned in $newHTML. I will work around that in my awful way by inserting a dummy word at the front and end of the string and strip it out after processing.

This is wonderful, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are requiring the server to do an awful lot of work up front. I suspect it would be a lot more efficient to populate a database of sizes offline (or maintain a cache of sizes).

And having done this, you could push the work out to the browser by using a cacheable javascript which sets the image sizes and is called inline at the end of the html (which has the advantage the you don't need to push all the html through you PHP code for rewriting). Hint: iterate through document.images[]

HTH

C.

Comment: This is not a bad idea as an alternative. It would not be the end of the world if somebody circumvented this javascript, for instance, so it's not critical to have PHP do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getimagesize() but it would be smart to store this information once and reuse it, or at least cache aggressively (as it's unlikely to change often) or your server will crawl to a halt with higher load

Comment: Is caching really an issue, when PHP only has to do the heavy lifting of downloading a remote image and examining it upon a user posting an image to the site? It will not have to be called on every page load, as it will change the HTML written to the database that is retrieved and inserted verbatim in the thread display script.

Images may only be posted a handful of times a day.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is accepted. I am sharing my code that uses cache.

```
function addImageAttributes($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Disable libxml errors
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false); // Enable libxml errors

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');

        // Check if the image is an external URL
        if (filter_var($src, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $cacheKey = 'image_' . md5($src);
            $imageSize = apc_fetch($cacheKey); // Use an appropriate caching mechanism (e.g., APC)

            if ($imageSize === false) {
                // If not found in cache, fetch and store the image size
                $imageSize = @getimagesize($src);
                if ($imageSize !== false) {
                    apc_store($cacheKey, $imageSize); // Store in cache for future use
                }
            }

            if ($imageSize !== false) {
                list($width, $height) = $imageSize;
                $image->setAttribute('width', $width);
                $image->setAttribute('height', $height);
            }
        }
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}

// Example usage:
$html = 'Here are two images: <img src="http://example.com/image.png"> <img src="http://example.com/image2.png">';
$processedHtml = addImageAttributes($html);

echo $processedHtml;
```

This example uses the Alternative PHP Cache (APC) to store and retrieve image dimensions. Make sure to enable and configure APC on your server. You can replace APC with other caching mechanisms like Redis, Memcached, or even a simple file-based cache, depending on your server environment and requirements. Caching helps reduce the overhead of repeated `getimagesize()` calls and improves the performance of your function.

Comment: @AlexanderFleming please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. If you have a new question that came up while trying to implement an answer, follow the usual procedure - look for duplicates, clearly formulate the problem (in particular, choose one specific problem, i.e. one specific technology you want to use), and if necessary ask a separate question.