# Automatically add width and height attributes to image tag

Tags: html, jekyll

I am trying to write a script that automatically add image `width` and `height` to all my `img`. I've already seen this question:

[Automatically adding width and height attributes to <img> tags with a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157516/automatically-adding-width-and-height-attributes-to-img-tags-with-a-php-functi)

But I am using `jekyll`.

My first thought was execute `grep` on my posts directory and for each occurence of an img, get the image `URI` and compute its size. Is this possible?

I have also take a look to `fastImage`, but it does not work well with Jekyll and local files ([Here is a Jekyll filter](https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll/blob/master/amp_filter.rb))

Could you give me some hits on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could just use JavaScript to do this on the client side. Is there a reason that wouldn't work for you? I'd also be curious to hear why you need to do this at all.

Comment: @KevinWorkman because I am implementing Google AMP pages and the amp-img needs those attributes to be specified.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Image tags should always have height and width attributes, but they're not required in order to display. Every SEO tool will flag them up if missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution, a python script, here it is (I've also created a [github gist)](https://gist.github.com/elbaulp/188a7f9d24e586cb16d9ed9188aa5823).

Here is the main idea behind the code:

- Iterate over all blog posts.
- Find all `img` tags in each post.
- Extract the content of the `src` attribute.
- Open the image and extract its size.
- Write image size in the `img` attribues `width` and `height`.

The code:

```
#!/bin/python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from os.path import basename, splitext
from PIL import Image
import glob

# Path where the posts are, in markdown format
path = "/ruta/ficheros/*.md"

# Iterate over all posts
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    # Open the post
    f = open(fname)
    # Create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    f.close()
    # For each img tag:
    for img in soup.findAll('img'):
        if img != None:
            try:
                if img['src'].startswith("/assets") == True:
                    # Open the image
                    pil = Image.open("/ruta/carpeta/imagenes" + img['src'])
                    # Get its size
                    width, height = pil.size
                    # Modify img tag with image size
                    img['width'] = str(width) + "px"
                    img['height'] = str(height) + "px"
            except KeyError:
                pass
    # Save the updated post
    with open(fname, "wb") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

## How to use

Just create the script in you machine and change `path` variable to point where your posts are.

Hope it helps, I've also [wrote a blog post about this issue](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/automatically-add-width-and-height-attributes-to-image-tag/)

Comment: Where did you add it? Could you explain how to use it?

Comment: @Alvaro Hi, I updated the answer, commenting on the code and giving general steps. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but still not clear to me. What language is it? How do you execute it? What is BeautifulSoup ?

Comment: It is python, you need yo save te code in a file, give it execution permissions, run it.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin ([jekyll-image-size](https://github.com/generalui/jekyll-image-size)) that does basically this, but it does it as a tag in your templates. For example, you can do this:

```
{% imagesize /assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg:img %}
```

And it generates:

```html
<a href="/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" width='300' height='150'>
```

(with the actual width and height of the image file)

It also supports retina-image-scaling and many alternate output-formats beyond just IMG tags: opengraph tags, css-style props, html-props, and the raw width and height of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this C tool for my own needs :

https://github.com/jfdelnero/TrucsEnVrac/tree/master/Tools/patch_html

This tool checks / fixes / add any missing/bad img "width" and "height" attributes. It also add any missing "alt" img attribute.

Run on Linux and need the "convert" tool.